# c++ perform operations on lists of varied primitives

Tags: c++, templates, generics, types, unions

I'm writing an interpreter for a simple scripting language, and I'm running into problems performing arithmetic operations on the variables. I need to make two lists of primitives, where every element in the list can be a different primitive type. So that's uint, int, float, and bool, along with different numbers of bits for the numerics: 8, 16, 32 and 64.

Then I need to perform some arithmetic operation between an element from list 1 and an element in list 2, and store the result. But I can't find any elegant way of doing it.

The best I've come up with is to make a union of all the primitive types an element can hold, and an enumeration to say which one to use. I'd make a switch statement to get the correct primitive type from the union, which would let me get the value from list 1. Then I'd have to write a second switch statement to get the value from list 2, and a third one to find out the variable type of the result.

In this example, GenericPrimitive is a class that contains the union of primitives and an enumeration that specifies which union type to use:

```
void DoOperation(vector<GenericPrimitive> first, vector<GenericPrimitive> second, GenericPrimitive& result)
{
    switch (first.at(0).PrimitiveType())
    {
        case PT_UINT8_T: return DoOperationOnT<uint8_t>(first.at(0).GetValueAsUInt8T(), second, result);
        ...

template <class T>
void DoOperationOnT(T firstValue, vector<GenericPrimitive> second, GenericPrimitive& result)
{
    switch (second.at(0).PrimitiveType())
    {
        case PT_INT16_T: return DoOperationOnTAndU<T, int16_t>(firstValue, second.at(0).GetValueAsInt16T(), result);
        ...

template <class T, class U>
void DoOperationOnTAndU(T firstValue, U secondValue, GenericPrimitive& result)
{
    switch (result.PrimitiveType())
    {
        case FLOAT: StoreOpResultAsFloat<T, U>(firstValue, secondValue, result);
        ...

template <class T, class U>
void StoreOpResultAsFloat(T firstValue, U secondValue, GenericPrimitive& result)
{
    switch (OperationType)
    {
        case ADDITION: result.SetFloat(AddValues<T, U, float>(firstValue, secondValue));
        ....

template <class T, class U, class V>
V AddValues(T first, U second)
{
    return (V)(T + U);
}
```

All these switch statements are inefficient. Is there some simpler or faster way I'm missing? I just want to know the types T U and V for my AddValues function without having to recalculate them every time. (or do something else that gives the same effect)

Comment: `std::variant` maybe? It's said to be modern c++'s replacement for `union`.

Comment: *"I need to make two lists of primitives, where every element in the list can be a different primitive type.", "Then I need to perform some arithmetic operation between an element from list 1 and an element in list 2, and store the result."*. Can you give more detail as to why you need this functionality? How is this related to your scripting language? For a binary operation of two types `U` and `V`, what is the return type of the result? If your scripting language is dynamically typed, how do you determine the types `U` and `V`?

Comment: Why are you tackling this problem specifically with lists? What happens when you have a simple `x+y` kind of expression?

Comment: The language is statically typed. If there's a line: "float x = y + z", where y is a uint8_t and z is an int16_t, the compiler turns the variables into stack references. I'll get an instruction like "interpret the first byte of the stack as a uint8_t, interpret the fifth and sixth bytes as an int16_t, add them, and store the result as a 4-byte float starting at the 10th byte on the stack." I was planning to scrap the union and have GenericVariable contain an index and bytecount on the stack, and cast those bytes to the desired primitive type. But a union makes it easier to explain I think.

Comment: Wait, are you writing a compiler or an interpreter? In the first case, performance wouldn't be such a big issue as in the second case...

Comment: A statically type language would have types like "list of int32" or "list of int16". If it has just "list", it is not really statically typed.

Comment: I have the feeling there are some problems with the terminology here. I think we are dealing with a strongly typed interpreted language that implements tuples.

Comment: I think your design can go one of two ways: If the number of types and operations is fixed and the language is not meant to be extendable without rewriting the interpreter, a solution using enums and possibly `std::variant` seems appropriate, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74747076/12173376) is a good starting point. You can use switches, polymorphism or type erasure to delegate to the correct operation. You should benchmark what works best for you. If you don't know all operations/types in advance, you probably need some sort of type erasure mechanism.

Comment: There's a misunderstanding here: I am writing the interpreter, which has a list of instructions in its implementation. The scripting language itself does not implement lists. I'm studying that answer now - I've never used variadic templates before.

Comment: It is still unclear why your interpreter would need to traverse a list of operands rather than a list of operations where each type of operation has known operand types.

Comment: I presume we need to find the correct overload of the operation based on the return type, and we need to ensure that the operands must be castable to the return type before calling the overload after the cast. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

I'd profile first before making assumptions, but still: I'm going to assume that you overlooked one important common case: `first.[0].PrimitiveType()==first.[0].PrimitiveType()` - in which case you only need one `switch`. Mixed-mode arithmetic tends to be rare.

(Also, I assumed that the `.at(0)` was an unintentional bounds check - there really should be a comment in code that intentionally uses `.at`)

Answer (score 0):

I would start by re-evaluating your template usage. If the goal is to eliminate the repeated usage of switch statements, I recommend using functors, enums, and variadic templates:

```
struct AddValuesFunctor
{
  template<class V, class T, class U>
  V operator()(T firstValue, U secondValue)
  {
    return static_cast<V>(firstValue) + static_cast<V>(secondValue)
  }
}
```

It looks like you are already using an enum of typing, but just to cover all my bases, I will mention that you will need one for this next piece of code.

The next step would be to add a variadic template like so:

```
template <class FuncT, class... ArgsT>
auto RunExemplarSwitch(FuncT&& func, Typing enumValueRepresentingType, ArgsT&&... args)
{
  switch(enumValueRepresentingType)
  {
   case Typing::FLOAT: {
     return func.template operator()<float>(std::forward<ArgsT>(args)...);
   }
   case Typing::Boolean: {
     return func.template operator()<bool>(std::forward<ArgsT>(args)...);
   }
   ...
   default:
   { 
     throw std::runtime_error("Unhandled Type Passed In");
   }
}
```

And since your template structure should be able to determine values of the `firstValue` and `secondValue` the variadic template should implement the typing of `class V`

The actual function call looks like this [assuming you are parsing the entire vectors and they are of equal length]:

```
vector<GenericPrimitive> first;
vector<GenericPrimitive> second;
for(size_t sharedIndex = 0; sharedIndex < first.size(); sharedIndex++)
{
  RunExemplarSwitch(AddValuesFunctor{}, Typing::FLOAT, first[sharedIndex], second[sharedIndex]);
}
```

This will likely have to be adapted to fit your specific use case, but hopefully using an implementation like this will help cut down on switch usage.

PS: This is my first post so I apologize if its not up to par.